# The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n+1) \sin(n)}{n \tan(n)}$

Tags: analysis, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln(n+1) \sin(n)}{n \tan(n)}$$

No idea what to do with this one! Have tried writing out as series but that method is extremely complicated. L'hopitals doesn't work here either

Answer (score 3):

For $n>0$,

$$u_n=\frac {\ln (n+1)}{n+1}\frac {n+1}{n}\cos (n)$$
$$\implies$$
$$|u_n|\leq 2\frac {\ln (n+1)}{n+1} $$

but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln (n+1)}{n+1}=0$
thus
$u_n $ goes to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\ln(n+1)sin(n)}{n \tan n}=\frac{\ln{(n+1)} \cos{n}}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use squeeze theorem $$0\le \left| \frac { \ln { \left( n+1 \right) \sin { \left( n \right)  }  }  }{ n\tan { \left( n \right)  }  }  \right| =\left| \frac { \ln { \left( n+1 \right) \cos { \left( n \right)  }  }  }{ n }  \right| =\left| \frac { \ln { \left( n+1 \right)  }  }{ n }  \right| \left| \cos { \left( n \right)  }  \right| \le \left| \frac { \ln { \left( n+1 \right)  }  }{ n }  \right| $$